# Logic Apps Saving CSV file as Bytes in Blob Storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to automate the process of receiving a scheduled email with an attached csv file and then overwriting the file in blob storage. However, the file is saved a json with bytes, not csv.

logic app design:

[image: This is my logic app design]

what is saved:
[image: This is what is saved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Attachments Content`：

[image]